# How to upload css/js code in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I've below css code to hide suite bar. Could you please help me to how to apply this code for my site. I tried two options but in both cases the result is not showing.

1. Copied below code in notepad and saved with name in double column `"suitebar.css"` and save in site asset library (not sure how to refer)
2. Then second option edit the home page and under Insert option --> Embed Code. Paste this below code but I think this is also not right procedure.

Please advise.

```
/* Hide the left Suite Bar and right ribbon areas */
#suiteBarLeft {
    display: none;
}
#RibbonContainer-TabRowRight {
    display: none !important; /* !important needed to override SharePoint inline style */
}

/* Float the Suite Bar to remove from document flow and allow ribbon to move up */
#suiteBar {
    float: right;
    width: auto;
}

/* Alter stacking order and set positioning for ribbon */
#s4-ribbonrow {
    z-index: -1;  /* Allows Suite Bar to show on top of Ribbon */
    position: static;  /* Secret sauce - needed to maintain ribbon functionality */
}
```

Comment: Do you want to use this code only on one page, or on the entire site?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the site in SharePoint designer
2. Edit the current master page and add following before `</head>`

   ```
   <SharePoint:CssRegistration ID="CssRegistration1" name="<% $SPUrl:~SiteCollection/SiteAssets/suitebar.css %>"
   ```
3. Save and publish the master page